# Handle Errors/While-True-Loop etc. in QML-Testcases

Tags: qt, unit-testing, error-handling, qml, qtquick2

When I get an error in a single `Test` in `QML`, all my following Tests will not be executed. I´ve tried a `Try-Catch-Block`but that did not work. Is there a good solution to solve this problem.

My second problem is, if I run into a `While-True-Loop`I could not get out of it. You can imagine what the problem is.

Can I build up something like a `WatchDog`that solves all my problems.

**EDIT**

```js
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtTest 1.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2


TestCase{
    id: myTestCase
    name:"ComboBoxTest"
    when: windowShown
    height: 100
    width: 100

    ListModel{
        id:myModel
        ListElement{text1:"Tom"}
        ListElement{text1:"Jerry"}
        ListElement{text1:"Micky"}
        ListElement{text1:"Donald"}
    }

    ComboBox {
        id:myCombo
        model: myModel

    }
  
    TextField{
        id:myTextField
        text:"Fufu"
    }

    function test_open(){
       myCombo.focus = true
       mouseClick(myCombo)
       console.log("Focus: " + myCombo.focus )
       keyClick(Qt.Key_Down)
       keyClick(Qt.Key_Down)
       keyClick(Qt.Key_Enter)

       verify(myCombo.currentText === "Micky",myCombo.currentText)
    }
  
    function test_copy(){
       myTextField.forceActiveFocus()
       myTextField.selectAll()
       //Get Fatal-Error and Testautomatism aborts completely
       keyClick(Qt.Key_Copy)
    }

  //While-True-Loop Problem
  function test_shouldFail(){
        while(true){
            ;
        }
    }
  
  


}
```

Comment: Please post some code that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: I added some Code that probably shows my problems